# Привязка объекта к нескольким окнам

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть два окна, которые в DataContext получают один общий объект и отображают его. В качестве объекта используется визуальный компонент System.Windows.Share.Rectangle. Далее окна поочередно отображаются. Собственно проблема в том что после отображения второго окна объект исчезает из первого и отображается во втором окне. Подскажите с чем это связано и как это решить.
PS: Если в качестве общего объекта использовать строку, то все будет отображается корректно.

Comment: Ну дык надо использовать шаблоны, а не контролы. Контрол может иметь только одного родителя в дереве!

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас будет

Comment: с шаблонами - сейчас попробую

Comment: Ну и если вы привязываетесь к VM, то в VM не должно быть никаких контролов. Почему бы не использовать Rect (или свой класс), а не Rectangle? А уже в GUI делать привязку из Rectangle в Rect

Comment: Понял свою ошибку. Сделаю как было предложено. Благодарю за внимание.

Comment: Потом ответ оформите, полезный вопрос.